# Manually approving the account in shopify after registration

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Whenever the user register on my Shopify website i want that account to be disabled until admin enable it from back-end panel. Currently when user is registered, his account is enabled by default.

Have searched various forums even tried Shopify support but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options. why you are not putting "request membership" sign up form instead of sign in form (disable from [here](https://www.shopify.com/admin/settings/checkout))? You could use the contact page for that if you wanted. Then you get an email when they fill that out. You would create the account (just copy and paste the info) and email them an invitation. They click the link in the invite to make the password. **(I think it will be a tedious task for you)**

Otherwise, let them create the account, but hide the pages with the [Locksmith](https://apps.shopify.com/locksmith) app. Then after you approve them you would apply a "tag" to the customer account so they can see the pages and products locked with [Locksmith](https://apps.shopify.com/locksmith).